# ExoPlayer play from cache fails when origin URL needs headers

Tags: android, caching, audio-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

My MediaItem is created fromUri with headers (needs auth) which i did using:

```
DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().setUserAgent(Util.getUserAgent(context, context.resources.getString(R.string.app_name))).setDefaultRequestProperties(Collections.singletonMap("Authorization", "Bearer $token"))
```

I then store it in the cache by using:

```
fun downloadMedia(url: String, mediaItem: MediaItem, metadata: String) {
        //the download request
        val helper = DownloadHelper.forMediaItem(this, mediaItem)
        helper.prepare(object : DownloadHelper.Callback {
            override fun onPrepared(helper: DownloadHelper) {
                val download =
                    helper.getDownloadRequest(url, Util.getUtf8Bytes(metadata))
                //sending the request to the download service
                DownloadService.sendAddDownload(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    MyDownload::class.java,
                    download,
                    true
                )
            }

            override fun onPrepareError(helper: DownloadHelper, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, e.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })

    }
```

Then i create the playlist by checking if an item is already cached, add the cached item, else get from url like so:

```
downed = (activity as MainActivity).getDownloadedItems().contains(mediaItem)
            if (downed) {

                val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                    requireContext(), Util.getUserAgent(
                        requireContext(), getString(
                            R.string.app_name
                        )
                    )
                )
                val cachedDataSourceFactory = CacheDataSource.Factory()
                    .setCache((requireContext().applicationContext as App).appContainer.downloadCache)
                    .setCacheReadDataSourceFactory(
                        dataSourceFactory
                    )

                val mediaSource =
                    ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cachedDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(
                        mediaItem
                    )
                podcastPlaylistSources.add(mediaSource)
            } else {
                val properties = HashMap<String, String>()
                properties["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token"

                val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().setUserAgent(Util.getUserAgent(requireContext(), requireContext().resources.getString(R.string.app_name))).setDefaultRequestProperties(Collections.singletonMap("Authorization", "Bearer $token"))

                val mediaSource: MediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(mediaItem)
                podcastPlaylistSources.add(mediaSource)
            }
```

Here's my problem:
When the URL i fetch the mp3 from is just a regular open mp3 stream, no problem, works fine.
But when i have an URL which needs headers for authentication, the streaming is fine, it's stored fine, but when i want to play from the cache i get:

```
ExoPlaybackException: Source error
Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
```

What is so different from a cached item from a regular stream vs header-needing-stream?
How do i fix my problem?

**EDIT:**
Could it be the DownloadRequest needs the headers somehow?

Comment: Did you find any solution for your issue? Do you know how to download HLS videos with the latest version of exoplayer?

Comment: @smbdy No i didn't. Eventually I just put a redownload in the failed function. Sow hen playing from cache fails, just redownload. It makes it "work", but the data usage gets a lot higher obviously

Comment: I have this issue https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/9583 do you maybe know what I did wrong?